# plugin_dir_path wrong url

Tags: plugin-development

```
  echo "background-image: url(" . plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/images/bag.png);';
```

output:

```
url(/home/deniztas/oneclick.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-content/plugins/my_post_plugin-bag2-solda/widgets//images/bag.png)
```

I want this:

```
oneclick.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-content/plugins/my_post_plugin-bag2-solda/widgets//images/bag.png)
```

why /home/.. comes to my url?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_url/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you are using the wrong function. You should use:

```
plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'images/bag.png';
```

Also remove the extra forward slash before images:

```
/images
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I spend long times to fix it